# how to insert rows and columns after every existing row and column in an excel worksheet?

Tags: excel

```
import openpyxl as xl;

filename = "C:\po.xlsx"
wb1 = xl.load_workbook("C:\po.xlsx")
ws1 = wb1.worksheets[0]
```

So this is what I have done so far just to begin with. Pls help me with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to SO. You can do this by using `insert_rows()` and `insert_cols()`, which are part of the openpyxl. The documentation is available [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html). Hope this helps.

```
import openpyxl

filename = "C:\po.xlsx"
wb1 = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb1.worksheets[0]
for r_idx in range(ws.max_row, 1, -1):
    ws.insert_rows(r_idx)
for c_idx in range(ws.max_column, 1, -1):
    ws.insert_cols(c_idx)
wb1.save("destination.xlsx")
```

The output would like this...

[image]

Comment: But there is a problem as my excel file does not save when I add the changes, so I want to make a destination file to put the saved changes in.

Comment: If you want to save the result in another separate file, change the name in the last line - `wb.save("destination.xlsx")`. That will create a new file with the updated contents. Is that what you require?

Comment: @Shrahbeel - Glad it worked. I have updated the response as well. If this has resolved your question, can you please close the question by accepting the answer. You can click the green tick mark next to the answer to accept this. Thanks !